# Watch CustomResourceDefinitions (CRD) with client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have added a new CRD `ApiGateway` to Kubernetes and I want to watch for new/changed resources of it.

This works with a simple Rest Client as shown in the example below.

But I´d like to watch for these resources with `k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes`.

While it is simple to get the standard resources like in the client-go example below , I don´t get anything working for CRDs.
Is it possible to get that done with client-go?

**client-go example for standard resources**

```
import (
    ....
    "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
)

func handleNewServices(clientset *kubernetes.Clientset) {
    for {
        serviceStreamWatcher, err := clientset.CoreV1().Services("").Watch(metav1.ListOptions{})
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        //fmt.Printf("%T\n", serviceStreamWatcher)
        for {
            select {
            case event := <-serviceStreamWatcher.ResultChan():
            service := event.Object.(*v1.Service)

            for key, value := range service.Labels {
                fmt.Printf("Key, VAlue: %s %s\n", key, value)
            }
...
```

**RestClient (working fine)**

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    ....

)

func main() {
    for {
        // Url "cw.com" must match the config spec.group in api-gateway-crd.yaml
        // URL "apigateways" must match the config spec.names.plural in api-gateway-crd.yaml
        resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:8001/apis/cw.com/v1/apigateways?watch=true")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        decoder := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
        for {
            var event v1.ApiGatewayWatchEvent
            if err := decoder.Decode(&event); err == io.EOF {
                break
            } else if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            log.Printf("Received watch event: %s: %s: \n", event.Type, event.Object.Metadata.Name)

        }
    }

}
```

**CRD**

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: apigateways.cw.com
spec:
  scope: Namespaced
  group: cw.com
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: ApiGateway
    singular: apigateway
    plural: apigateways
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you think about it, `client-go` knows about `deployments`, `services`, `pods` etc resources. But it doesn't recognize your CRD `ApiGateway`.

So, `client-go` can't be used as a client for your custom made resources (wait-for-it), unless you made them recognizable to `client-go`!

**How?!**

You have to generate your own client for the CRDs. Kubernetes already have the tools to auto-generate the clients, all you need to specify the `structs` of `API`. This is known as `code-generation`.

Here is a [blog post about code generation](https://blog.openshift.com/kubernetes-deep-dive-code-generation-customresources/) by [STEFAN SCHIMANSKI](https://github.com/sttts) (who is one of the top contributors to kubernetes).

**Example Controller**

Here is a [sample-controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/sample-controller) example given by kubernetes itself. The `pkg` folder contains all the `APIS` and `Client`. The `main.go` and `controller.go` contains the sample code to watch for the CRD and do some task accordingly.

**!!Update!!**

It's easier now to generate client configs and controllers with kubebuilder ([github repo](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubebuilder)), which is maintained by kubernetes-sigs.

Answer (score 6):

Using [dynamic](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/tree/master/dynamic) package of client-go may be a good choice to operate CRD.

Basically watch example:

```
cliSet, err := dynamic.NewForConfig(&rest.Config{})
if err != nil {
    return err
}

cliSet.Resource(schema.GroupVersionResource{
    // replace it with your CRD's corresponding property
    Group:    CRDGroup,
    Version:  CRDVersion,
    Resource: CRDResourceName,
}).Watch(context.Background(), metav1.ListOptions{})
```

Advanced watch, informer example:

```
cliSet, err := dynamic.NewForConfig(&rest.Config{})
if err != nil {
    return err
}

fac := dynamicinformer.NewFilteredDynamicSharedInformerFactory(cliSet, 0, metav1.NamespaceAll, nil)
informer := fac.ForResource(schema.GroupVersionResource{
    // replace it with your CRD's corresponding property 
    Group:    CRDGroup,
    Version:  CRDVersion,
    Resource: CRDResourceName,
}).Informer()

informer.AddEventHandler(cache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{
    AddFunc: func(obj interface{}) {
        // converting the dynamic object to your CRD struct
        typedObj := obj.(*unstructured.Unstructured)
        bytes, _ := typedObj.MarshalJSON()
        
        var crdObj *crd.CRD
        json.Unmarshal(bytes, &crdObj)
    },
    UpdateFunc: func(oldObj, newObj interface{}) {
        
    },
})
```