# Creating a k8s controller that watches all kinds in a single api group

Tags: go, kubebuilder

I need to write a k8s controller using kubebuilder that watches objects of all `kinds` in a `api group`. It should also support dynamic kinds in the api group. That is if a new CRD is installed that belongs to the same api group and an instance of it is created then the controller should pick it up.

Is this possible at all? What are some of the other alternatives? e.g. hard-code the `kinds` (or take it from a config) and use the `watches` function to monitor the resources?

Comment: You can read(on startup)/watch CR**D**s (`apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/CustomResourceDefinition`), filter them and add dynamic watchers for the C**R**s you wish to react to. I am not sure whether this is a good idea, though. It somehow defies the whole concept of an operator, imho: "Do one thing and do it good."

Comment: How would `add dynamic watchers for the CRs` work? Is it possible to add a code snippet for this?

Comment: Erm...  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71950402/1296707 and then `for _, cr := range crds; <setup watcher>`? ;) Maybe a map would be more suitable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some of the ideas from comments, I was able to make it work like the  below. The code is  part of the `SetupWithManager` function. The idea is to listen for CRDs and then dynamically create controllers based on `GVK`

```
builder.Watches(crd, handler.EnqueueRequestsFromMapFunc(func(ctx context.Context, obj client.Object) []reconcile.Request {

        crd := obj.(*v1.CustomResourceDefinition)
        r.Queue.SetContext(ctx)
        customResource := &unstructured.Unstructured{}
        for _, version := range crd.Spec.Versions {
            gvk := schema.GroupVersionKind{
                Group:   crd.Spec.Group,
                Version: version.Name,
                Kind:    crd.Spec.Names.Kind,
            }
            // set GVK for unstructured object
            // this is needed to add a watch unstructured objects
            customResource.SetGroupVersionKind(gvk)
            // Create a new controller dynamically based on the CRD added within an API group
            err := ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
                For(customResource).
                Owns(crd).
                WithLogConstructor(func(request *reconcile.Request) logr.Logger {
                    return mgr.GetLogger()
                }).
                Complete(&myReconciler{client: mgr.GetClient(), gvk: gvk, Queue: r.Queue})
            if err != nil {
                mgr.GetLogger().Error(err, fmt.Sprintf("Unable to create a controller for %s", gvk))
            }
        }
        return []reconcile.Request{}
    }
```

I also filtered the CRDs using predicate function (not part of snippet above)

and then need a reconciler function like below

```
func (r *myReconciler) Reconcile(ctx context.Context, req ctrl.Request) (ctrl.Result, error) {
// this is invoked when objects of the filtered CRDs are created, updated etc.
}
```

The key really is to set the `GVK` on unstructured types. Understand this might be not recommended, because `Do one thing and do it good.` but it works for my specific use case.