# Implementing a custom Finalizer to Kubernetes resources

Tags: kubernetes

Seems [easy peasy](https://book.kubebuilder.io/reference/using-finalizers.html) to implement custom *finalizers* if I'm implementing my Kubernetes CRD: the code snippet is quite easy since the first delete request on the object sets a value for the `metadata.deletionTimestamp` field instead of deleting the object that triggers the custom controller watching the object to execute any finalizers it handles.

However, let's imagine I'd like to set a *custom finalizer* for a default Kubernetes resource like a Namespace, a Deployment or whatever: is that possible or not?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Is there something specific you've tried that's not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, tested a little bit taking `Namespace` as an example.

```sh
# k create ns my-namespace
namespace/my-namespace created

# k edit ns my-namespace
(... adding the .metadata.finalizers list)

# k get ns my-namespace -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-09-08T06:50:25Z"
  finalizers:
  - prometherion/do-something
  name: my-namespace
  resourceVersion: "1131"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/my-namespace
  uid: 75b5bae8-1d5b-44c6-86bc-e632341aabfd
spec:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes
status:
  phase: Active

# k delete ns my-namespace
namespace "my-namespace" deleted
```

If I open another terminal, I can see the resource in `Terminating` state.

```sh
# k get ns my-namespace
NAME           STATUS        AGE
my-namespace   Terminating   6m8s
```

So, actually the resource is marked to be deleted since I got a `deletionTimestamp`:

```sh
k get ns my-namespace -o jsonpath='{.metadata.deletionTimestamp}'
2019-09-08T06:58:07
```

To complete the deletion, I just need a simple [Watch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40975308/10104472) (using the Kubernetes Go Client) to get the change of the object (or a [Dynamic Admission Controll](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/) to get the event, process my business logic in async mode (like a pre delete hook) and remove my fully-qualified Finalizer... just for sake of simplicity, I tested removing it with `kubectl` and it worked.

Just for information, *Finalizer* must be fully qualified since there's a [validation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/core/validation/validation.go#L4676-L4680) process, so it must be declared according to the pattern `prometherion/whatever_you_want`, taking care the first part must adhere to `DNS-1123` specification.

Comment: Here's the specific code related to finalizer validation in kubernetes: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/13e3904f0f5149299f183c097e9a0970f18c0fd2/staging/src/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/validation/validation.go#L42